# Aggregate multiple columns at once

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data-frame likeso:

```
x <-
id1 id2    val1  val2 val3 val4
1   a   x    1    9
2   a   x    2    4
3   a   y    3    5
4   a   y    4    9
5   b   x    1    7
6   b   y    4    4
7   b   x    3    9
8   b   y    2    8
```

I wish to aggregate the above by id1 & id2. I want to be able to get the means for val1, val2, val3, val4 at the same time.

How do i do this?

This is what i currently have but it works just for 1 column:

```
agg <- aggregate(x$val1, list(id11 = x$id1, id2= x$id2), mean)
names(agg)[3] <- c("val1")  # Rename the column
```

Also, how do i rename the columns which are outputted as means in the same statement given above

Answer (score 91, accepted):

We can use the formula method of `aggregate`.  The variables on the 'rhs' of `~` are the grouping variables while the `.` represents all other variables in the 'df1' (from the example, we assume that we need the `mean` for all the columns except the grouping), specify the dataset and the function (`mean`).

```
aggregate(.~id1+id2, df1, mean)
```

---

Or we can use `summarise_each` from `dplyr` after grouping (`group_by`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(id1, id2) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Or using `summarise` with `across` (`dplyr` devel version - `‘0.8.99.9000’`)

```
df1 %>% 
    group_by(id1, id2) %>%
    summarise(across(starts_with('val'), mean))
```

---

Or another option is `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, grouped by 'id1' and 'id2', we loop through the subset of data.table (`.SD`) and get the `mean`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = .(id1, id2)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", 
"b", "b"
), id2 = c("x", "x", "y", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y"), 
val1 = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), val2 = c(9L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 
9L, 8L)), .Names = c("id1", "id2", "val1", "val2"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. Is df1 suppsed to be a function which needs ot be defined? It will be very helpful if you can explain the above syntax

Comment: @Rookie `df1` is the data.frame object

Comment: What's the intuition about the formula in the aggregate version involving a sum, if it's a cartesian product really? Or perhaps it's that it treats the sum as the unique identifying value? So i.e. (a,x) and (a,y) are identified by a+x != a+y, rather than (a=a,x!=y).

Answer (score 36):

You could try:

```
agg <- aggregate(list(x$val1, x$val2, x$val3, x$val4), by = list(x$id1, x$id2), mean)
```

Comment: please elaborate your answer-review

Comment: Nice going (+1). So if you provide a list instead of a vector as argument x (first one), `aggregate` will compute the aggregate for each value in the list.

Comment: Also, you can rename all columns returning from the `aggregate` call, by giving each list component a name, such as `agg <- aggregate(list(val1=x$val1, val2=x$val2, val3=x$val3, val4=x$val4), by = list(id1=x$id1, id2=x$id2), mean)`. This will replace the default column names assigned by `aggregate`.

Comment: Can I also change the function for each aggregation?? (example: sum val1 but take mean of val2 and val3)

Comment: it will auto-sort the columns which is not desirable in every  case